# Hosting a Etherdelta like frontend

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

i got a (etherdelta-like) decentralized exchange script and decided to install it on cpanel as i am not very familiar with linux commandline as the installation instruction is done with ubuntu commandline (https://bitexchange.systems/help/viewtopic.php?t=237). But it does not seem to be working. Is there a way i can use mysql for the offchain record instead of mongodb? here is what i have at acecrypto.io.

Comment: You have to write the front end in a language such as HTML then use JavaScript to communicate with your backend.

Comment: You can use mySQL, but we are not here to write the code for you. You need to write it and if you have any SPECIFIC questions you can ask them here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. the frontend is already coded in html and javascript. I just want to be sure it can be installed via cpanel instead of through commandline

Comment: Yes. I will write an answer of how you can install it on cpanel

Comment: Please check my answer below. If it helped you, please mark it as correct and up vote it

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: your answer worked and i have actually done that earlier. just that it seems i am not able to make the script work afterwards

Comment: Well post a new ? with a detailed question of where you are struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload it by following these steps:

1. Login to Cpanel
2. Click `File Manager`
3. Select the `Web Root (public_html/www)` option and click `Go`
4. Click the `Upload` button
5. Click `Browse` and upload all of the HTML, JS, CSS, and any other website assets
6. Click `Upload`
7. Test your website is accesible